# JWT Authentication in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am currently working on a `react-admin` project with the backend API server at `localhost:8000/api` using `Django REST` framework and `django-rest-framework-simplejwt`. The endpoints exposed from the backend API are `admin/`, `api/`, `api/token/` and `api/token/refresh/`. I have tried to implement custom `authProvider` code similar as in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ra-menu-nc2sd?file=/src/authProvider.js) following this [github repo](https://github.com/marmelab/ra-in-memory-jwt/tree/master/demo/admin) and [this blogpost](https://marmelab.com/blog/2020/07/02/manage-your-jwt-react-admin-authentication-in-memory.html)

Note that the codesandbox only serves as an example implementation of my frontend.

When I try to login with the correct credentials of Django admin, I am momentarily logged in to the dashboard page and instantly redirected to the login page. How do I get around this to work? Is there a simpler implementation to this, say using a third-party library/module?

P.S I can't change the backend code as I work only on the frontend. Also, I have not used [drfProvider](https://github.com/synaptic-cl/ra-data-drf) as data provider as it doesn't support `react-admin@3.x.x`and encountered too many errors when I downgraded to `react-admin@2.x.x`

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? Plus what data provider did you end up using? new to react and I'm faced with a similar problem... I want to login and return some data from my drf API

Comment: @cgitosh Sorry. I have stopped working on this project for quite sometime while I was focusing on another project. Will update if I get around this in the future